PKIX path building failed SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I'm encountering an error while developing an Android plugin. When I run the plugin to generate a JAR file. I receive the following error message:
Error Message
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
:

I'd like to understand the cause of this error and successfully generate the JAR file for my Android plugin.
Could you please help me diagnose the error and suggest solutions based on the error message and any additional information I can provide?

Does this answer your question? "PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

The cause is that you are connecting to a server via HTTPS and the server does not use a certificate from a CA that is trusted by Java. You can perform an SSL check of the server that will check for common problems including the used server certificate and it's certificate chain.

i have fixed this issue after changing my Network provider.
